# Spread sheet view of a database in android

Tags: android, database

I want to know if there is a possibility of getting a database in a spread sheet view similar to excel or SQLServer. 
I tried converting the database file into txt which I did get results but not the clear one I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you pull the information out of the database, create a tableview and then just populate the cells/rows, and you have a spreadsheet view.

You could also just save it as a delimited string and email it somewhere so you can open it in excel.

Comment: Question: Do you mean tableView for android? If so would that mean I have to run it on a seperate project? With just tables?.

Comment: You can have a different activity for this tableview, as a project can have any number of activities.

Comment: That's true. Thanks I will definitely try that.